# what does html > signify in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have below CSS code in some CSS file of Liferay portal.

What does **html >** signify? When that should be used?

```
.lfr-dockbar-pinned {
    .dockbar {
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .pin-dockbar img {
        background-image: url(../images/dockbar/unpin.png);
    }
}

html > .lfr-dockbar-pinned {
    padding-top: 3.45em;
}
```

Comment: Curious why one would select `html > .lfr-dockbar-pinned` - is that class attached to the `body` element?

Comment: Yes its attached to `body` element. Here is the code - `<body class=" controls-hidden lfr-dockbar-pinned guest-community signed-in public-page">` . Not sure why they (Liferay) have done so..

Comment: @VikasV Probably that's a joomla template

Comment: I wonder why `html >` would be necessary. Perhaps an IE6 hack? Usually the hack starts with `html > body` and not just `html >`.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess `html body {}` is equivalent here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An element with the class `lfr-dockbar-pinned` that is a direct child descendant of the `html` element. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 2):

It represents an element that is a direct descendant of the html element (As @adrian told).

In other words it selects all elements where the parent element is `<html>` which in this case would be only `<body>`

So for example

```
div > p {
   /* This will select all p elements where parent is div */
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete. Normally you don't open with "In other words" - that expression means you've tried to say something in one way, then you're stating it "in other words" in another way.

Answer (score 1):

It selects the child element.

Eg: body > p selects all < p> elements that are direct child elements of the  element.

Answer (score 1):

Given this code (from your comment):

```
<body class="... lfr-dockbar-pinned ...">
```

In this case it distinguishes between the body, when it has the class `lfr-dockbar-pinned`, and another element having the same class. This allows different styling to be applied to each of those elements.

Comment: But `body` is a direct descendant of `html`.

Comment: This is the only case that really makes sense. '<head>' and '<body>' should be the only DIRECT decendants of '<html>', so the only time that would apply is when the '<body>' tag has a class. (In this case 'lfr-dockbar-pinned')

Comment: BoltClock, you're right. I momentarily confused myself there.